# @PUT and @Post in Jersey2

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I get 415 err in my configuration Spring Boot, JQuery, Html templates jn WildFly 10.
@PUT and @POST:

```
    @POST
    //@Path("/create")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createCustomers(@FormParam("firstname") String firstname,
                                    @FormParam("lastname") String lastname,
                                    @FormParam("email") String email,
                                    @FormParam("dateborn") String dateborn,
                                    @FormParam("pass") String pass,
                                    @Context UriInfo uriInf
    ){
        CustomersEntity customer = new CustomersEntity();
        customer.setFirstname(firstname);
        customer.setLastname(lastname);
        customer.setEmail(email);
        customer.setDateborn(dateborn);
        customer.setPass(pass);
        customerService.save(customer);
        long id = customer.getId();

        URI createdUri = uriInf.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(Long.toString(id)).build();
        return Response.created(createdUri).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response updateCustomers(@PathParam("id") Long id,

                                @FormParam("customerFn") String firstname,
                                    @FormParam("customerLn") String lastname,
                                    @FormParam("customerEmail") String email,
                                    @FormParam("customerDb") String dateborn,
                                    @FormParam("customerPass") String pass
                                   ) {
        CustomersEntity inDb = customerService.findOne(id);
        if (inDb == null){
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        else {
        inDb.setFirstname(firstname);
        inDb.setLastname(lastname);
        inDb.setEmail(email);
        inDb.setDateborn(dateborn);
        inDb.setPass(pass);
        customerService.update(inDb);
        }
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
```

HTML form:

```
<form id="customerForm" method="POST" action="/customers">

    <div class="mainArea">

        <label>Id:</label>
        <input id="custId" name="id" type="text" disabled="disabled" />

        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="custFn" name="customerFn" required="required" />

        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="custLn" name="customerLn" />

        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="custEmail" name="customerEmail" />

        <label>Date Born:</label>
        <input type="text" id="custDb" name="customerDb" />

        <label>Pass:</label>
        <input type="text" id="custPass" name="customerPass" />

        <button id="btnSaveCustomer">Save</button>
        <button id="btnDeleteCustomer">Delete</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

part JQuery:

```
function addCustomer() {
    console.log('addCustomer');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: customerlistURL,// + '/create',
        dataType: "json",
        data: formToJSON(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('Customer created successfully');
            $('#btnDeleteCustomer').show();
            $('#custId').val(data.id);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('addCustomer error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}

function updateCustomer() {
    console.log('updateCustomer');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: customerlistURL + '/' + $('#custId').val(),
        dataType: "json",
        data: formToJSON(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('Customer updated successfully');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('updateCustomer error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}

function deleteCustomer() {
    console.log('deleteCustomer ' + $('#custId').val());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: customerlistURL + '/' + $('#custId').val(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('Customer deleted successfully');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('deleteCustomer error');
        }
    });
}
```

And I get:

Response Header:
    Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type
    Connection: keep-alive
    Date: Mon, 12 Jun 2017 15:33:06 GMT
    Server: WildFly/10
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    X-Powered-By: Undertow/1

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
```

Other methods(all @GET-s and @DELETE) work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reflection and study of this issue, I found the answer. Jax-rs Jarsey2 configuration extracts data and data-format from the request body no need to use additional annotations for conversion from the HTML-form:

```
    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response updateCustomers(@PathParam("id") Long id,
                                    CustomersEntity customer){
        CustomersEntity existCustomer = customerService.findOne(id);
        if (existCustomer == null){
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        else {
            existCustomer.setFirstname(customer.getFirstname());
            existCustomer.setLastname(customer.getLastname());
            existCustomer.setEmail(customer.getEmail());
            existCustomer.setDateborn(customer.getDateborn());
            existCustomer.setPass(customer.getPass());
            customerService.update(customer);
        }
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the error message, you may not use `@FormParam` with content types other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: When I added enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in Html-form and change @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) I got same error. What I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know. Are you sure it is the very same error?

Comment: yes, I always get same error. With or without @Consumes and enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in Html. If I tried used @QueryParam("firstname")... et.c, I get "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
  Подробности: Failing row contains (8, null, null, null, null, null)."   The configuration only sees" id ", not else.